# How to use LUT files in Blender?

Tags: python, lut

Guys did you find a simple way to use ready LUTs in Blender?

Comment: Hello, a little bit more background to your question would maybe help potential solutions arise :) Are you talking about view transforms ?

Comment: @Gorgious Yes. I mean using custom LUTs in Blender